# jquery .html is reloading the page only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, reload

I have this function that's re-writing html in a div. It's to make an image gallery with rollover effects on the displayed image. Only in Chrome, the page fully reloads and brings you back to the top of the page. How can I stop this? It works fine in FF and IE.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
 $(".imagegrid").click(function(e){
  var newIMG = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#show").html("<img id='displaypic' src='Images/Photoshop/"+newIMG+"After1.jpg' onmouseover=\"this.src='Images/Photoshop/"+newIMG+"Before.jpg'\" onmouseout=\"this.src='Images/Photoshop/"+newIMG+"After.jpg'\">");
    })   
});
```

The original link looks like this:

```
<img id="Oakley" class="imagegrid" src="Images/Photoshop/OakleyThumb.jpg" height="150">
```

I've tried to add a
    
to try and get it to force the refresh to that section of the page as a workaround and that doesn't work at either.

This is the effect I'm looking for:
    http://www.retouche.com/site/Portfolio.aspx?id=svc102

Comment: Okay so I think I figured it out... I've yet to fully test it across all browsers though:

Answer (score 0):

changing the CSS instead of the image itself worked out the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
 $(".imagegrid").click(function(e){
  var newIMG = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#galleryshow").css("background-image", "url(Images/"+newIMG+"after.jpg)");
  $("#galleryshow").hover(function(){
    $("#galleryshow").css("background-image", "url(Images/"+newIMG+"before.jpg)");
  },function(){
    $("#galleryshow").css("background-image", "url(Images/"+newIMG+"after.jpg)");
    });
  })   
});
```

Comment: Psst. Try the `:hover` pseudo selector in you stylesheet.